# convexity of the function $f(x,y)=x^4-\alpha y^2$

Tags: real-analysis

To study the convexity of this function I calculate the Hessian:

$$\begin{bmatrix}12x^2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2\alpha \end{bmatrix}$$

For $\alpha<0$ the matrix is semidefinite-positive so the function is convex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of fact, this function is strictly convex if $\alpha$ is negative. Both $x^4$ and $-\alpha y^2$ are strictly convex and, hence, their sum is also strictly convex.